# Onclick popup div close when clicked outside of it

Tags: javascript

How can I add to this to make the pop up close when anywhere on the page is clicked?
Thanks

```js
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a div behind the popup with low opacity that covers the entire page, and add an event listener that toggles "show" when it's clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the event listener to the `document` and on click check if the `myPopup` `contains` the `show` class. If true then use `classList.remove`

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  if (popup.classList.contains("show")) {
    popup.classList.remove('show')
  }
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a layer that spans the entire screen behind the popup and listen the click on that element. Whenever somebody clicks inside of the popup, check if the clicked element (`target)` is the outer popup layer and hide the popup if it is.

```js
const popup = document.getElementById('myPopup');

function onPopupClick(event) {
  const { target } = event;
  if (target === popup) {
    popup.classList.remove('show');
  }
}

popup.addEventListener('click', onPopupClick);
```

```css
.popup {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 350ms ease-in-out, visibility 350ms ease-in-out;
}

.popup.show {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.popup__inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 0 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="myPopup" class="popup show">
  <div class="popup__inner">
    <p>I'm a popup. <br>Click in the white square and see nothing happens</p>
    <p>Click outside of me and I will close.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a custom implementation.

```
- Use a button click event to show and hide the popup.
- Use a body click event and check whether the ckick event is inside or outside the popup.
- If the click is inside the popup, do nothing. Or else hide the popup.
```

```js
function myFunction(event) {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  // popup.classList.toggle("show");
  if (popup.style.display === "none") {
    popup.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    popup.style.display = "none";
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
}

function onBodyClick(event) {
  var myTarget = event.target;
  while (myTarget) {
    if (myTarget.id === "myPopup") {
      console.log("You clicked Inside popup");
      return;
    } else {
      myTarget = myTarget.parentNode;
    }
  }
  console.log("You clicked Outside popup");
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  if (popup.style.display === "block") {
    myFunction(event);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
#myPopup {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body onclick="onBodyClick(event)">
  Outside Popup
  <button onclick="myFunction(event)">Open Popup</button>
  <div id="myPopup" style="display: none;">
    Inside Popup
    <span>
      Inner node
    </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please use `addEventListener` for calling functions on event and toggling between classes instead of inline styles. Inline events and styles are generally more difficult to work with and make your HTML do JS and CSS tasks.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier using inline events or add eventlistener is wrt the developers comfort level, You could chose any one of the method depending on your comfort. I find this way to be more useful. If you are using any kind of frontend frameworks, going with an add event listener method is not preferred.

Comment: Your last point is quite interesting, as I am interested to learn what frameworks you refer to. In my experience they use `addEventListener` under the hood, like React.js and Angular do. The argument has a side of preference, granted. It's that I've seen many others implore people to give the right example by using best practices (in this case: separation of concern) and up-to-date techniques. Inline styles are notoriously hard to overwrite (only with `!important`) and removes the power from CSS.

Comment: @NitheeshI got it on my page. It works but I have 4 popups ad click anywhere on page will only close the last one. How can I make it work for the all.